# Parameterize apex:param value on a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, salesforcedx, dynamic-visualforce

I've got a list of fields that I want display on a Visualforce page.

I can get this to work:

```
<apex:repeat var="animal" value="{!animals}" id="lotsofanimals">  
                           <apex:outputText value=""  >
                                <apex:param value="{!animal['Color_Dog']}" /> 
                           </apex:outputText>
                           <apex:outputText value=""  >
                                <apex:param value="{!animal['Color_Bird']}" /> 
                           </apex:outputText>
                           <apex:outputText value=""  >
                                <apex:param value="{!animal['Color_Cat']}" /> 
                           </apex:outputText>
                           <apex:outputText value=""  >
                                <apex:param value="{!animal['Color_Horse']}" /> 
                           </apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```

So I thought a better way would be to store 'Color_Dog', 'Color_Cat', etc in its own object and then pass that in. The Name being the field I want to display

and this works:

```
<apex:repeat var="animal" value="{!animals}" id="lotsofanimals">  
    <apex:repeat var="traits" value="{!animalstraits}" id="lotsofanimalstraits">  
                           <apex:outputText value=""  >
                                <apex:param value="{!animal[traits.Name]}" /> 
                           </apex:outputText>
       </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
```

So I thought I could abstract it one more time with something like this:

```
<apex:repeat var="animal" value="{!animals}" id="lotsofanimals">  
    <apex:repeat var="species" value="{!animalsspecies}" id="lotsofanimalspecies">  
                           <apex:outputText value=""  >
                                <apex:param value="'Color_'{!animal[traits.species]}" /> 
                           </apex:outputText>
       </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
```

But that's when I get the error:

The value attribute on `<apex:outputText>` is not in a valid format. It must be a positive number, and of type Number, Date, Time, or Choice.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

One idea I had was to further abstract it again with 'Color_', 'Weight_',etc as another object and then put a 3rd repeat

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything to be resolved needs to be in the merge field, so it'd be:

```
"{!animal['Color_'&traits.species]}"
```

I'm not entirely sure that format is supported, but this would be the syntax required.

Comment: I was missing the '&' when I tried 'Color_' inside the []. Thanks!!